# Установить недостающие пакеты не устанавливая уже установленные, чтобы сохранить/pin их версии

Tags: ubuntu, apt-get, package, dpkg, deb

У меня есть папка с содержимым из /var/cache/apt/archive/ , в ней все пакеты(deb-пакеты), которые я устанавливал на данном ПК с ОС Ubuntu. Я эту папку в виде архива перенесу на другой ПК с ОС Ubuntu, разархивирую. Я могу все эти пакеты установить командой:

```
dpkg -i /те/файлы/из/var/cache/apt/archive/*.deb
```

Но эта команда установит все пакеты, а мне нужно установить только те пакеты, которые еще не установлены, а те которые установлены нужно пропустить.

Comment: ответ целиком и полностью зависит от того, по какой причине «нужно пропустить».

Comment: @alexanderbarakin по причине того, что они уже установлены.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin установленные пакеты сами пропустятся ?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin в честь того что мне нужны уже установленные версии, а не те которые я хочу пропустиь.

Comment: о! причина появилась. так уберите из каталога те версии пакетов, который вам не подходят. но, насколько я понял, вы следуете советам из предыдущих ваших вопросов, и будьте готовы к тому, что если не обновите пакеты, требующие обновления, то зависящие от этих новых версий не будут нормально сконфигурированы, а следовательно, возможно, останутся в не-рабочем (или полу-рабочем) состоянии. удачи вам!

Comment: на данный вопрос объективно верный и полезный ответ дать невозможно. вам надо задать *другой* вопрос по поводу синхронизации между двумя машинами, одна из которых без интернета, уточнив, что *некоторые* пакеты в оффлайновой системе вам надо [за-pin-ить](https://wiki.debian.org/ru/AptPreferences). это потребует внесения корректив в процедуру синхронизации/получения/установки.